# Change cell contents to bold after inserting text from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using vba code to copy a value from another column into blank cells in Column B. I want the copied value to be bold.

I'm using the following to populate the blank cells in column B:

```
Sub CatLabels()
    x = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If x > 1 Then
        With Range("B2:B" & x).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[+1]C[+2])"
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I get the copied value to be changed to a bold font?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I don't think that will work. I think you need `Range("A1").Font.Bold=True`

Comment: Quite right....

Comment: How do I use Range("A1").Font.Bold=True ? The copied cells are in Column B.

Comment: Between ```.FormulaR1C1 = "=(R[+1]C[+2])"``` and ```End With```, insert ```.Font.Bold=True```, assuming it's only blank cells that you want to change.

Comment: You change the cell reference to reflect the cell or cells you wish to Bold. (*That was stated in @cybernetic.nomad comment which he has since deleted*)